# \r inserted into child.before

Tags: python, pexpect

I have a 54 chars command being sent over SSH to a Voltha CLI server using child.sendline() [preprovision_olt -t ponsim_olt -H olt.voltha.svc:50060]
I expect to be able to match on that  such that I remove it from the child.before the next time around
However I never can match because the output from child.before() has a '\r' char inserted near the end which truncates the output
This is what the output from child.before() looks like

`60reprovision_olt -t ponsim_olt -H olt.voltha.svc:500`

A '\r' is being inserted after 500 resulting in the following two chars overwriting the first two chars

Why is this so?

This is the code I have:

```
def send_command_to_voltha_cli(logDir, cmd, logFile):
vcliIp = extractIpAddr('vcli')
print (vcliIp)
print (cmd)
output = open(logDir + '/' + logFile, 'w')
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh -p 5022 -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no voltha@' + vcliIp)
child.expect('[pP]assword:')
child.sendline('admin')
child.expect('\([0-9]mvoltha.*[0-9]m\) ')
bytes = child.sendline(cmd)
print (bytes)
child.expect_exact(cmd)
child.expect('\([0-9]mvoltha.*[0-9]m\) ')
response = child.before
print (response)
output.write(child.before)

output.close()
child.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a voltha thing Only the preprovision_olt command is behaving like this I will simply work around this by once having collected the mangled sent command using child.before as the first line in the log file, I will simply delete the first line of the file